# How to install packages for pypy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypy

I've installed `pip` for `pypy`,and successfully installed `requests`, `BeautifulSoup4`.
Then,i am trying to install `psycopg2` and `gevent`.
Both return the following

```
Command "/usr/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-OJcoXb/gevent/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qsGmuG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-OJcoXb/gevent/
```

Comment: Many packages won't work with Pypy.  According to [this page](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/compatibility/wiki/psycopg2) there is an alternate version of psycopg2 that does work with pypy, but regular pscyopg2 won't work.

Comment: gevent can be installed on PyPy2.  The CPython C API emulation part is not as polished with PyPy3, so maybe it doesn't work there yet.